# Response.Redirect() in iFrame, redirect parent window

Tags: asp.net, iframe, redirect, response.redirect

I know this isn't possible, but what is the best alternative for wanting to do `Response.Redirect` from an iFrame, to redirect the parent page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not do this using ASP.NET. ASP.NET on server side can redirect incoming request and can't know about a parent frame.

But if you want to redirect parent frame  on some server side condition you can call JavaScript from server like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
       "RedirectScript", "window.parent.location = 'http://yoursite.com'", true);
}
```

And of course you can use simple JavaScript window.parent.location = 'http://yoursite.com' on client side.

Comment: Note that the domains of the frame and parent frame documents will need to match to avoid an access denied error being thrown by most browsers.

Comment: If my parent has another domain in the frame?

Answer (score 9):

I just used the following code with success. It even bypassed the `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` and allows redirection from one domain to another one in an iframe:

```
string url = "https://siteurl.com";
Response.Write("<script>top.location='"+url+"';parent.location='"+url+"';</script>");
```

With [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) (since C# 6):

```
string url = "https://siteurl.com";
Response.Write($"<script>top.location='{url}';parent.location='{url}';</script>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.Clear();
Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"
<script type=""text/javascript"">
top.location = ""/Logout.aspx"";
parent.location = ""/Logout.aspx"";
</script>
"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    url = "Your.asp?YourVar="&YourVar
    %> \end your classic asp code and pass to the script below
    <script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location.href = '<%= url %>'</scrip>
```