# Where is RegisterClientScriptBlock()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using asp.net 4.0.  I have access to ClientScriptManager but when I try to type in RegisterClientScriptBlock(), there is no intellisense and I get an error about a static method.  I was looking at [Response.Redirect() in iFrame, redirect parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307285/response-redirect-in-iframe-redirect-parent-window) as an example.  Apparently there is some difference.

The page I'm on does inherit from System.Web.UI.Page.  What is the proper way to use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)**

> Registers the client script with the Page object using a type, key, and script literal.

Notice it specificly states it works with a `Page` object.

The Page object has a [ClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript.aspx) property of type `ClientScriptManager` and therefore you can use `RegisterClientScriptBlock()`.

If you're inheriting from Page (sorry, missed that part) just use `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` for example:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"MyMethod","alert(1);", true);
```

Comment: I inherit from Page, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

use

`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

and dont forget to add a script manager to your page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it on [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)

Comment: See the OP. That's what I'm doing.